# Data structure that allows accessing elements by index and delete them in O(1)

Tags: algorithm

I have following task (as part of bigger task):

I need to take an `k` element from array like data structure and delete it (k is any possible index). Array have O(n) for deleting elements, and List have O(n) for searching element. I would like to do both operations in O(1) time.

Which data structure should I use to meet this requirement?

Clarification:

Deleting element on index(5) will move element from index(6) to index(5).

This particular task is topcoder srm 300 div2 500 points problem. It does not require such sophisticated data structure (simple java methods will do the job since max data is really small), but I am curious how to deal with much bigger problem using c-like thinking about data.

So maybe I am sticked to much to array for this problem? But I will analyze it and edit question later, after work (if you are really curious, you can see task on top coder).

Comment: What language? You have sets and hash tables to begin with.

Comment: A simple array doesn't work because...?

Comment: Could you clarify whether after deleting element at index 5, does the element at index 6 change indexes so that it now has index 5?

Comment: @Mehrdad Because it has `O(n)` deletions?

Comment: @H2CO3: Huh? Just set the element to null... isn't that the same thing a hashtable would do?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think it's supposed that the rest part is shifted after deletion, though it needs clarification from OP

Comment: @Mehrdad Well, then what about the indices? If you rely on an element being in the array not being null, then you have to search through the array when indexing. And that's `O(log n)` in the best case... (or again `O(n)` for an unsorted array.)

Comment: @H2CO3 see my comment -- OP needs to clarify

Comment: @randomstring No need for further clarification. An array is an array, regardless of what Mehrdad thinks it is. [Do we believe Wikipedia?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Efficiency)

Comment: @H2CO3 in that case, hash table doesn't work (not that that is your suggestion). OP, please clarify the semantics you want.

Comment: @randomstring Yes, that's what I'm saying (and if we disguise a hash table as a null-padded array, it *still* doesn't work.)

Comment: Sorted or unsorted array? If the array is unsorted, you can delete in `O(1)`: Instead of moving elements to fill the gap, fill it with the element in the last position and decrement its size by one.

Comment: @DanielMartín Even if it's unsorted, that doesn't mean the order isn't important (but it could still be the case that the order really doesn't matter and your idea works).

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you're asking for is impossible.

However, if you can relax your requirement for indexing to O(log n), then [ropes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) may be able to satisfy it, although I'm not sure if they have a probabilistic or deterministic guarantee (I think it's probabilistic).

Comment: i agree with impossibility because keys need to be shifted if array-like behavior is needed. O(log(n)) is the best to hope for.

Comment: @BenJackson: You'd need an indexable skip list (I don't know how they work)... normal ones don't support indexing.

Comment: `O(log n)` can be viewed as a constant anyway because memory is bounded so n is too.

Comment: @usr: It really depends... I don't think that's a safe assumption here. For example, mergesort is O(n log n), which is quite slower than a typical O(n) algorithms... you can't usually ignore O(log n) factors that actually change the amount of work you do.

Comment: If all you care about is worst case bounds you can assume `log n = 30` in the case of merge sort because it will never be more. If you also care about the actual value of the constant factor you are right.

Comment: Maybe I'm taking the OPs question too literally. I gave you +1 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of the "dating" problem as given, it involves continuously choosing and removing the "best" member of a set--a classic priority queue. In fact, you'll need to build two of those (for men and women). You'll either have to build them in O(NlogN) time (a sorted list) for constant O(1) removal, or else build them in linear time (a heap) for O(logN) removal. Overall you get O(NlogN) either way, since you'll be removing all of one queue and most of the other.

So then the question is what structure supports the other part of the task, choosing the "chooser" from the circle and removing him and his choice. Since this too must be done N times, any method that accomplishes the removal in O(logN) time won't increase the overall complexity of your algorithm. You can't get O(1) indexed access with fast deletions given the re-indexing requirement. But you can in fact get O(logN) for both indexed access and deletion with a tree (something like a rope as mentioned). This will give you O(NlogN) overall, which is the best you can do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, that may be satisfying in some cases. You have to use an array and a vector for saving deletions. Every time you delete an element, you put its index in a vector. Every time you read an element of some index, you recalculate its index depending on previous deletions.

Say, you have an array of:

```
A = [3, 7, 6, 4, 3]
```

You delete 3-rd element:

```
A = [3, 7, 6, 4, 3] (no actual deletion)
d = [3]
```

And then read the 4-th:

```
i = 4
3 < 4 => i += 1
A[i] = 3
```

This is not exactly O(1), but yet it does not depend on array length. Only on a number of deleted elements.

Comment: In the challenge given, every element will be eventually removed, so this is no better than a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

The only data-structure that has a small overhead in adding and removing element is an hashtable. The only overhead is the cost of the hash function (and it is considered as O(1), if you take a purely theoretic approach).

But, if you want it to be extremely efficient, you will need to:

- Have an approximate of the number of elements you will have to get inside your data-structure (and allocate this number once for all at the beginning).
- Choose an hash function that will avoid collision given the way your keys are distributed (collisions are just breaking the efficiency of hashtables).

If you manage to get everything right, then you should be optimal.

Comment: Operations are O(1), but you'll have to modify all elements with a larger index (which will take O(n)).

Comment: @Dukeling: Why ? You just insert it at the location noted by the hash. If you have a collision, then you use a linked list (buckets). You will never have to reorder anything... Collision is the only risk where you might loose performance as I said.

Comment: The lookup is by index. When deleting an index, all indices following that index decreases by one, thus their hash values will also change.

Comment: It just means that you need an iterator on the structure, not that the index have to be contiguous. Or, am I missing something ?

Comment: No, @perror is correct. A Hashtable is usually represented with a sparse array where each hash modulo the size of the table is the index. However, this also means that changing the "amount of buckets" is going to be very costly, so you'll want a fair estimate on how big a table you need to begin with.

Comment: You have to be able to delete the k-th element in O(1). I don't see how you can do this more than once with your approach.

Comment: @kqr: Thanks, at some point I though I was totally wrong ! ;-)

Comment: @Dukeling With hash tables, you usually don't delete the *k* th element, you delete an element with hash *H*. Which makes it possible to represent the table with a sparse array. (I.e. an array with "gaps" – not all the possible hashes are associated with a value.)

Comment: @kqr That's exactly my point, the question asks for a data structure to delete the k-th element efficiently, so hash tables won't really work.

Comment: @Dukeling: Aside to your hashtable, you can easily maintain an iterator function that will keep track of linear access to the data-structure (eg. with a linked list). Insertion and deletion will be of cost O(1), until you reach the limit of the preallocated table.

Comment: @perror I'm not sure how a linked-list will help. Sure, insertions and deletions will be O(1), but only once you have the element at the desired index, which you'll have to iterate through the linked-list to find, which takes O(n).